# Grabbing, storing and using all interfaces in the solution, when the interfaces are <T>

Tags: c#, generics

Stumped on this one. I had this method:

```
private static List<IBiscuitTransformer> GetBiscuitTransformers()
 {
     var type = typeof(IBiscuitTransformer);
     var transformers = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes().Where(c => !c.IsInterface))
         .Where(p => type.IsAssignableFrom(p))
         .Select(c => (IBiscuitTransformer)Activator.CreateInstance(c))
         .ToList();

     return transformers;
 }
```

This worked great. I had several implementations of BiscuitTransformer, and all was biscuity goodness.

However, the problem is that I want `IBiscuitTransformer` to have a method that takes in `List<T> biscuitBarrelBiscuits` as a parameter. This seems to force me to make `IBiscuitTransformer` into `IBiscuitsTransformer<T>`, which I don't really want, but may be unavoiable.

Once I do this, I don't know how to modify the above code so I can create an instance of all the classes that implement `IBiscuitTransformer<T>`. Possibly because I don't know `T`? Or I can't figure out the syntax. But I shouldn't need to know `T` to create an instance, it's only a method call that I want to take in `T`. It is only the method on the objects `TransformBiscuit(List<T> biscuitBarrelBiscuits)` that I want to be generic, not the class itself, so it should be possible to create an instance of it with Activator.

But I can't figure out how to do it, or if it's even possible. Any ideas?

Just to explain what I am trying to do, I have a bunch of biscuit transformers that take in biscuits and transform them. There is one for each type of biscuit, and I load them via reflection into an array so I can choose which one to use when a biscuit comes in. The transformers all have a common interface, with a `TransformBiscuit` method on them, but because they take in a collection of different types of biscuit, it has to be a List in order for them to all be able to use the same interface.

I'm not sure if I just can't figure out the concept or if I'm fundamentally doing it wrong.

Comment: `I want IBiscuitTransformer to have a method that takes in List<T> biscuitBarrelBiscuits as a parameter` . it is not necessary to have generic interface `IBiscuitsTransformer<T>` for that, generic method  `void Do<T>(List<T> L);` in IBiscuitTransformer interface is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the method generic.

```
void TransformBiscuit<T>(List<T> biscuitBarrelBiscuits)
```

This is assuming that a single instance of `BiscuitTransformer` will be able to transform any top of biscuits that you would pass in, of course.

Comment: Think you might have solved it, forgot you could put <T> after the method name instead of having to declare it at the class level!

Comment: Yes this works but makes me think I've architected it wrong. I'm using `T` but `T` is always going to be the same thing, because in the `DigestiveBiscuitTransformer` I know that `T` will always be a `DigestiveBiscuit`.

Comment: Sounds like your interface needs to be generic and your implementations work on a specific type.  `IBiscuitTransformer<T>` - `DigestiveBiscuitTransformer : IBiscuitTransformer<DigestiveBiscuit>`